# Approximation of Forward Rates in discrete time

Tags: interest-rates, finance-mathematics, mathematics, forward-rate

The forward rate from time $t$ to $T$ ($f_{t,T}$) can be approximated by:

$$
f_{t,T}= \left[ \frac{(1+r_T)^T}{(1+r_t)^t} \right]^{\frac{1}{{T-t}}}-1
\sim
\frac{(1+r_T)^T-(1+r_t)^t}{T-t}
$$

**Why is that the case?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may show it as follows:
\begin{align*}
f_{t,T}&= \left[ \frac{(1+r_T)^T}{(1+r_t)^t} \right]^{\frac{1}{T-t}}-1\\
&=e^{\frac{1}{T-t} \left[\ln (1+r_T)^T - \ln (1+r_t)^t \right]} -1\\
&\approx e^{\frac{1}{T-t} \left[(1+r_T)^T-1 - \big((1+r_t)^t -1\big)\right]} -1\\
&=e^{\frac{1}{T-t} \left[(1+r_T)^T - (1+r_t)^t\right]} -1\\
&\approx 1+ \frac{1}{T-t} \left[(1+r_T)^T - (1+r_t)^t\right] -1\\
&=\frac{1}{T-t} \left[(1+r_T)^T - (1+r_t)^t\right].
\end{align*}